# Is it possible to remove the previous callsign information?

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

I had a name change some years ago and had a new callsign generated. But the FCC keeping a record of my previous callsign puts me at risk of an abusive ex finding me.

Is it possible to disassociate the old callsign from my FCC record so there's no more link between my old callsign with an old name and my new callsign with my new name?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so but you can try by contacting the FCC and explain the problem, the worst that can happen is nothing the best you get expunged. Also be aware there are a lot of paper records and they probably cannot change or remove them. It is also probably published in one or more of the many call sign books and references published. Here are three links that might help, good luck.

https://www.rmda.army.mil/records-management/docs/ARIMS_Quarterly_Report_of_all_RRS_Instructions_with_ACRS_Crosswalk-20210603.xlsx

https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/FCC-18-174A1.pdf

https://www.mcieast.marines.mil/Portals/33/5210_1%20CH-1.pdf